# Clock striking problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

> Two clocks begin to strike 11 together. The first clock strikes every stroke in 3 seconds while the second strikes in 2 seconds. What is the interval between the first clock’s fifth stroke and the second clock’s seventh stoke?
>
> (A) 1 sec
>
> (B) 2 sec
>
> (C) 5 sec
>
> (D) No time interval

It seems the answer is straight forward by $1=3*5-2*7$, i.e. $(A)$. However, the answer turns out to be $(D)$. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the first stroke is the one at 11 o'clock. They will strike together the first time. So you get one less time interval each and thus you have $0 = 3\cdot 4 - 2\cdot 6$.